# AndroidStudio: EditText keyboard doesn't appears / No input

Tags: android-studio

At first sorry for my bad english.

I'd like to have a search function for my ListView. Now I have a EditText, but when I click the EditText the line only went blue and than black again. No Keyboard - No Input. I searched about this topic but all solutions aren't working. When I open the keyboard programmly and type on a letter nothing happens.

(EditText went from invisible to visible)

**My EditText:**

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editSearch"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolBarBoden"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="75dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:hint="Search"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:theme="@style/EditTextTheme"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        tools:ignore="NotSibling"></EditText>
```

**I tried:**

RequestFocus (programmly and xml), ClearFocus, open keyboard programmly

Comment: Please show the code that creates it also.

Comment: Create: https://hastebin.com/ixitizuyom.java